# How change the background of a hyperlink (with image) when is selected (clicked)?

Tags: css

How can I change the background of a href (with image) when is selected (clicked)?

I have the next HTML code:

```
<li class="barButton" id="addHome">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="imgBar" id="animate1" src="img/interface.png" >
  </a>
</li>
```

and I've tried the next CSS code:

```
.imgBar:active {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

But the background of image-button only is changed when is clicked.

Comment: by "selected", do you mean when the mouse is hovering over it or when it is clicked?

Comment: `a:link` = unvisited link, `a:visited` = visited link, `a:hover` = mouse over link, `a:active` = selected link. What do you mean exactly by _"When is selected"_ ?

Comment: @JanDragsbaek. when it is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the `background-color` property to your `<img>`. If the image is not transparent or partially transparent, the background color will not be visible.

The `:active` pseudo-class is the correct selector to utilize when targeting the "clicked" state, more specifically, it equates to the "mousedown" state. You may be searching for the `:visited` pseudo-class which targets links that have previously been visited.

You should try targeting your anchor tag with the pseudo-class (e.g. `a:active .imgBar{ background-color: #000; }`). Remember that anchor elements are `display: inline;` by default, so it will match the image's width and height by default. If you still do not see the background color, try adding some padding to it and see if anything changes.

Comment: The image is transparent and I can see a change. I explain  it in the question. "the background of image-button only is changed when is clicked". Only in that moment

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using the active pseudo-class with the class you have on the img tag, rather than the anchor tag.

Try this: a:active .imgBar{background-color:#000}